# After updating Jenkins, logins fail with https://[jenkinsURL]/j_spring_security_check

Tags: authentication, jenkins, active-directory, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-update

I updated Jenkins from version 2.252 to 2.313. But then when I tried to login, I was redirected to the page https://[jenkinsURL]/j_spring_security_check with a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by updating the Jenkins "Active Directory" plugin to newer than version 2.17.

They mentioned the fix here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/active-directory-plugin/releases/tag/active-directory-2.17

After that, I was able to log in fine.

Comment: Maybe [JENKINS-64130](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64130) or [JENKINS-64369](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64369). Again, likely tables-to-divs issue; gotta read the upgrade guide.